what causes my configured test event xml url to not match the xml url in my AWS Lambda
appreciate any input on this. I'm creating my first web scraper starting first with an AWS Lambda function. Using Python 3.12. I have configured the JSON in a test event and should be able to match the test event XML URL to my sitemap URL in my scraping code. No matter what I do, it goes to my error condition and states its missing the sitemap URL in the event data. URLs changed to be an example.
Code snippet where I get the XML sitemap, with error handling:
# Get sitemap URL and return informative error if unable to
  sitemap_url = event.get("https://www.example.com/post-sitemap.xml")
  print(f"Retrieved sitemap URL: {sitemap_url}")
  if not sitemap_url:
    return "Error: Missing sitemap URL in event data. Please provide a valid sitemap URL."

Here is my configured test event for the lambda function:
{
  "sitemap_url": "https://www.example.com/post-sitemap.xml"
}

No matter what I try, my error condition is triggered. Have I missed something in the setup of the test event or incorrectly formatted the event JSON? Any tips would be appreciated!
I have completed the following.

Review the code where you retrieve the sitemap URL from the event data. To make sure you're using the correct key name (e.g., "sitemap_url") to access the value associated with the sitemap URL.
Verify that you're using the get method on the event object in the expected way.
Removed the XML URLs and re-typed, in case of char encoding issues from copy/paste, etc.

As I was writing this in the AWS Lambda function, I didn't see a debugger. Thought about the following items to help

adding additional logging. not sure of a good library, etc. Recommendations would be great
using a debugger


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is a little unclear and also includes some aspects that are off-topic for SO. Please read the [tour], [ask], and [mre] in their entirety, then come back and [edit] your question.
